# pasring JSON from string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

http://localhost/project1/index.php

```js
//AJAX region
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  success : function(data){
   console.log('success \n', data);
  },
  error : function(data){
   console.log('error', data);
  }
 });
});//AJAX region
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it's easily loading data from http://localhost/project1/json.php
console: 
[image]

data is string, if I use $.parseJSON(data) or JSON.parse(data) i get following error... 
[image]
[image]

I want data as realtime JSON object, so that I can access each properties & values.

Comment: Can you add the actual JSON to the post rather than a screenshot. That being said the screenshot doesn't appear to be valid JSON.

Comment: The "objects" within state 1, 2 ... n are invalids.  Probably the backend should return as arrays rather than objects.

Comment: Your `json.php` returns invalid JSON, how are you generating it? You should simply use `json_encode` PHP function and if you want to do it right before echoing it set the header to JSON with `header('Content-type: application/json');`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the JSON. All property names should also be enclosed in double quotes `"`, for example

Comment: Please add code from region.php. The problem appears to be there.

Comment: States inside country should be inside array `country: { [ { state: ..}, {state: ..} ] }, country: { .. }`

Comment: your json is not valid because of many different reasons. If you received a valid json your code should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Observation 1: unnecessary parseJSON

No need to call `parseJSON`.
Use `dataType` property of [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load your data directly in JSON format:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // here
    url : 'http://localhost/project1/region.php',
    success : function(data) {
        // data is already a JS object :)
        console.log('success \n', data);
    },
    error : function(data){
        console.log('error', data);
    }
});
```

#### Observation 2: wrong JSON

Code above will still throw the same error, because of

> unexpected token ,

It refers to the trailing comma after all the last elements your object and its children. Remove that comma and there will be no more errors.

For example:

```
"State1" : {
    "City 1",
    "City 2",
    "City 3",
}
```

There should NOT be a comma after `"City 3"`. The same goes for other states, and for whole `"country2"` object too.

There is another error: your States objects are **arrays**, but you are writing then as **objects**. Change curl brackets to square brackets for `"State1"` and `"State2"`.

Answer (score 1):

The json object you are returning is invalid json, for the state objects, you need to make them arrays. so:

"State1":["City1","City2","City3"]

When the parser parses this object it expects a second value per city like "City1 ": "Second Value"...since there is no second value its breaking.

Comment: {
 "country 1":{
  "State 1" : ["City 1","City 2","City 3"],
  "State 2" : ["City 1","City 2","City 3"],
 },
 "country 2":{
  "State 1" : ["City 1","City 2","City 3"],
  "State 2" : ["City 1","City 2","City 3"],
 },
}

but still error

Comment: ], }, } This is the last part, delete those commas.